# Using multiple variables summing with i++

Tags: c#, pdf

I want to sum a flexible number of PDF files that a user can drop in a form.
For a controllable number of files I can manage but I would like it to be flexible.

This is how I do it now for 2 PDF files:

```
 private void MergePdf_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
 {
     e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
     string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
     if (files.Length > 1) {return; }

     using (PdfDocument outPdf = new PdfDocument())
     using (PdfDocument pdf0 = PdfReader.Open(files[0], PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))
     using (PdfDocument pdf1 = PdfReader.Open(files[1], PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))
     {
         CopyPages(pdf0, outPdf);
         CopyPages(pdf1, outPdf);

         outPdf.Save("file1and2.pdf");

     }
  }

 void CopyPages(PdfDocument from, PdfDocument to)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < from.PageCount; i++)
     {
         to.AddPage(from.Pages[i]);
     }
 }
```

Now I would like to update the code so that the user is allowed to drop any number of files. 
This would mean that I have to create more `pdf[i]` variables depending on the size of my array `files[]`.

Is this possible in c# or should I just create 100 of these variables already and do a `try{} catch{}` on all of them?

Comment: Just use a loop over all elements in `files`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could loop over the files:

```
using (PdfDocument outPdf = new PdfDocument())
{
    foreach (string fileName in files) 
    {
        using (PdfDocument inPdf = PdfReader.Open(fileName, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))
        CopyPages(inPdf, outPdf);
    }
    outPdf.Save("file1and2.pdf");
}
```